# android opennlp build error: cannot access Path class file for java.nio.file.Path not found

Tags: android, gradle, java-8, opennlp

I am trying to use apache opennlp library for my android project. But build fails. As instructed in some SO posts I have checked my javac version which is 1.8.0. I have also added following compile options

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Then build error asked me to enable jack, which I did. But then I got the error mentioned in title. From a SO post I got to learn that not all Java packages are included in Android. So how do I use opennlp in my android project? Are there any other NLP libraries which are easier to integrate/use in Android?

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
android{
    jackOptions {
                enabled true
            }
}
```

add this in `gradle` project level.

Comment: As mentioned in question, I have tried enabling jack already like this. That is when I am getting this error.